# My website will not scroll when 100% zoomed in.

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my website able to scroll down when in 100% but it isn't working, the only way to view the whole page is if I zoom out to 80% Below is all the CSS and HTML. I've tried putting an Overflow:scroll for the main body of the page but it still didn't work. I still had to zoom out to view the page.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body {
  margin: 0;

}

#mainPage {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -5;
   
}

#navBar {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  Background-color: #1f1f1f;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 350px;
  font-family: "Economica", sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#Logo {
  margin-left: 70px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  font-family: "Economica";
  font-size: 49px;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#google {
  margin-left: 45px;
}

img {
  opacity: 0.3;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -3;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

#Events {
  top: 120px;
  left: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 245px;
  height: 370px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 21px;
  z-index: -2;
}

#eventList {
  padding-top: 130px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.event {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.lines {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.highlight {
  Padding-top: 20px;
  
  padding-bottom: 17px;
  padding-left: 44px;
  padding-right: 44px;
}

#select a:hover {
   
  background-color: #383838;
  transition: ease 0.2s;
}

#eventList a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  color: #ffe700;
  transition: ease 0.7s;
}

.eventLight {
  padding-right: 70px;
  padding-top: 17px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

#upComing {
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 450px;
  font-family: "economica";
  font-size: 65px;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 175px;
}

#box {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  width: 800px;
  height: 195px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#entireBox {
  width: 810px;
  height: 195px;
  border-radius: 17px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

#drake {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  width: 410px;
  height: 135px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: "economica";
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

#drakeBorder {
  width: 425px;
  height: 140px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

#ovo {
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 450px;
  padding-top: 545px;
}

#circle1 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 485px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

#circle1 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 485px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

#circle2 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 635px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

#circle3 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 829px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

#circle4 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 1010px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

#wembley {
  position: absolute;
  border: 0;
  width: 95px;
  height: 37px;
  margin-top: -27px;
  opacity: 1;
}

#mobile {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #333333;
  margin-left: -600px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -5;
}

.slider { 
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  height: 3px;
  width: 45px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: ease 1s;
}

#slideButton {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border: 0;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 7px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 18px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#slideButton:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#slideButton:hover {
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
  transition: ease 0.6s;
}

#listMobile {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: -318px;
}

.smallList {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 0;
  font-size: 45px;
}

#line {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 83px;
  width: 250px;
  border: none;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #646464;
}

.rainbow-button {
  width: 134px;
  height: 70px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #00C0FF 0%, #FFCF00 49%, #FC4F4F 80%, #00C0FF 100%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  margin-left: 350px;
  margin-top: 0;
  font-family: economica;
  position: fixed;
  color: #ffe700;
}

.rainbow-button:after {
  content: attr(title);
  width: 134px;
  height: 67px;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.rainbow-button:hover {
  background-color: #383838;
  animation: slidebg 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes slidebg {
  to {
    background-position: 20vw;
  }
}
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.holder {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: -220px;
}
.holder .circle {
  border-radius: 100% 100% 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}
.holder .circle:nth-child(1) {
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  z-index: 15;
  animation: circle-1 10s infinite ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes circle-1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
.holder .circle:nth-child(2) {
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 11px 11px 0 0;
  width: 11px;
  height: 5.5px;
  z-index: 14;
  animation: circle-2 10s infinite ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes circle-2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-720deg);
  }
}
.holder .circle:nth-child(3) {
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 22px 22px 0 0;
  width: 22px;
  height: 11px;
  z-index: 13;
  animation: circle-3 10s infinite ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes circle-3 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-1080deg);
  }
}
.holder .circle:nth-child(4) {
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 33px 33px 0 0;
  width: 33px;
  height: 16.5px;
  z-index: 12;
  animation: circle-4 10s infinite ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes circle-4 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-1440deg);
  }
}
.holder .circle:nth-child(5) {
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 44px 44px 0 0;
  width: 44px;
  height: 22px;
  z-index: 11;
  animation: circle-5 10s infinite ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes circle-5 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-1800deg);
  }
}
.holder .circle:nth-child(6) {
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 55px 55px 0 0;
  width: 55px;
  height: 27.5px;
  z-index: 10;
  animation: circle-6 10s infinite ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes circle-6 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-2160deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="IceArenaHome.css">
  
   <title>
      Ice Arena
   </title>
  
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Economica" rel="stylesheet">
</head>


<body>
   
   <div id="mainPage">
      <div id="ovo">
         <div id="drakeBorder">
            <div id="drake">
               
               Be here when rappers <span style="color:#ffe700;">X</span> and <span style="color:#ffe700;">Y</span> will be performing live on stage.
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="upComing">
         Upcoming Events:

         <div id="entireBox">
            <div id="box">
               
               Make sure you are here when <br>these two teams clash in the<span style="opacity:0;">.............<!-- i used these full stops to push my text to the right --> ......</span> <span style="color:#ffe700; font-size:40px;">Manchester United vs Ajax</span><br>               biggest match in European <br> football the Europa league final.
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      
      <img src="http://xoio.de/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/GMP_Tokyo_Stadium_Concert_interiorvisual_by_xoio1.jpg" alt="concert stadium" style="width:100%; position:absolute; padding-top:70px; height:930px">
      <div id="navBar">
         <div id="circle1" class="circles">
         </div>
         <div id="circle2" class="circles">
         </div>
         <div id="circle3" class="circles">
         </div>
         <div id="circle4" class="circles">
         </div>
         <div id="Logo">
            <div class="holder">
               <div class="circle"></div>
               <div class="circle"></div>
               <div class="circle"></div>
               <div class="circle"></div>
               <div class="circle"></div>
               <div class="circle"></div>
               <div class="circle"></div>
               <div class="circle"></div>
               <div class="circle"></div>
               <div class="circle"></div>
               <div class="circle"></div>
               <div class="circle"></div>
               <div class="circle"></div>
               <div class="circle"></div>
               <div class="circle"></div>
               <div class="circle"></div>
            </div> <span id="google">Ice Arena</span>

         </div>

         <ul id="select">
            <li>
               <a class="highlight" style="color:#ffe700;">Home
              </a> </li>
            <li><a class="highlight" href="IceArenaGallery.html">
               Gallery
           </a> </li>
            <li> <a class="highlight" href="IceArenaOrderForm.html">
               Order Form 
           </a> </li>
            <li> <a class="highlight" href="#">
               The Arena
            </a></li>
            <li><a class="highlight" href="#">
               Contact Us
           </a> </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
 
      <ul id="eventList">
         <li class="event"><a class="eventLight" href="#">
            All<strong style="opacity:0;">.....................</strong>
           </a>
            <hr class="lines">
         </li>
         <li class="event"><a class="eventLight" href="#">
               Sports <strong style="opacity:0;">.............</strong>
               </a>
            <hr class="lines"> </li>
         <li class="event"><a class="eventLight" href="#">
               Music<strong style="opacity:0;">...............</strong>
            </a>
            <hr class="lines">
         </li>
         <li class="event"><a class="eventLight" href="#">
               Family<strong style="opacity:0;">..............</strong>
            </a>
            <hr class="lines">
         </li>
         <li class="event"><a class="eventLight" href="#">
               Comedy<strong style="opacity:0;">............</strong>
           </a>
            <hr class="lines"> </li>

         <li class="event"><a class="eventLight" href="#">
               Performance<strong style="opacity:0;">...</strong>
            </a></li>

      </ul>
      
      <div id="Events" style="opacity:0.4;">

      </div>


   </div>
   
   
</body>
<a href="#" class="rainbow-button" title="Home"></a>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add:

```
html{
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Css 'overflow-y: scroll' creates scroll, as you expects.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body {
  margin: 0;

}

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#mainPage {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -5;
}

#navBar {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  Background-color: #1f1f1f;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 350px;
  font-family: "Economica", sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#Logo {
  margin-left: 70px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  font-family: "Economica";
  font-size: 49px;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#google {
  margin-left: 45px;
}

img {
  opacity: 0.3;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -3;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

#Events {
  top: 120px;
  left: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 245px;
  height: 370px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 21px;
  z-index: -2;
}

#eventList {
  padding-top: 130px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.event {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.lines {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.highlight {
  Padding-top: 20px;
  
  padding-bottom: 17px;
  padding-left: 44px;
  padding-right: 44px;
}

#select a:hover {
   
  background-color: #383838;
  transition: ease 0.2s;
}

#eventList a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  color: #ffe700;
  transition: ease 0.7s;
}

.eventLight {
  padding-right: 70px;
  padding-top: 17px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

#upComing {
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 450px;
  font-family: "economica";
  font-size: 65px;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 175px;
}

#box {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  width: 800px;
  height: 195px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#entireBox {
  width: 810px;
  height: 195px;
  border-radius: 17px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

#drake {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  width: 410px;
  height: 135px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: "economica";
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

#drakeBorder {
  width: 425px;
  height: 140px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

#ovo {
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 450px;
  padding-top: 545px;
}

#circle1 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 485px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

#circle1 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 485px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

#circle2 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 635px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

#circle3 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 829px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

#circle4 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 1010px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

#wembley {
  position: absolute;
  border: 0;
  width: 95px;
  height: 37px;
  margin-top: -27px;
  opacity: 1;
}

#mobile {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #333333;
  margin-left: -600px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -5;
}

.slider { 
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  height: 3px;
  width: 45px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: ease 1s;
}

#slideButton {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border: 0;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 7px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 18px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#slideButton:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#slideButton:hover {
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
  transition: ease 0.6s;
}

#listMobile {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: -318px;
}

.smallList {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 0;
  font-size: 45px;
}

#line {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 83px;
  width: 250px;
  border: none;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #646464;
}

.rainbow-button {
  width: 134px;
  height: 70px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #00C0FF 0%, #FFCF00 49%, #FC4F4F 80%, #00C0FF 100%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  margin-left: 350px;
  margin-top: 0;
  font-family: economica;
  position: fixed;
  color: #ffe700;
}

.rainbow-button:after {
  content: attr(title);
  width: 134px;
  height: 67px;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.rainbow-button:hover {
  background-color: #383838;
  animation: slidebg 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes slidebg {
  to {
    background-position: 20vw;
  }
}
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.holder {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: -220px;
}
.holder .circle {
  border-radius: 100% 100% 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}
.holder .circle:nth-child(1) {
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  z-index: 15;
  animation: circle-1 10s infinite ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes circle-1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
.holder .circle:nth-child(2) {
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 11px 11px 0 0;
  width: 11px;
  height: 5.5px;
  z-index: 14;
  animation: circle-2 10s infinite ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes circle-2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-720deg);
  }
}
.holder .circle:nth-child(3) {
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 22px 22px 0 0;
  width: 22px;
  height: 11px;
  z-index: 13;
  animation: circle-3 10s infinite ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes circle-3 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-1080deg);
  }
}
.holder .circle:nth-child(4) {
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 33px 33px 0 0;
  width: 33px;
  height: 16.5px;
  z-index: 12;
  animation: circle-4 10s infinite ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes circle-4 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-1440deg);
  }
}
.holder .circle:nth-child(5) {
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 44px 44px 0 0;
  width: 44px;
  height: 22px;
  z-index: 11;
  animation: circle-5 10s infinite ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes circle-5 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-1800deg);
  }
}
.holder .circle:nth-child(6) {
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 55px 55px 0 0;
  width: 55px;
  height: 27.5px;
  z-index: 10;
  animation: circle-6 10s infinite ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes circle-6 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-2160deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="IceArenaHome.css">
  
   <title>
      Ice Arena
   </title>
  
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Economica" rel="stylesheet">
</head>


<body>
   
   <div id="mainPage">
      <div id="ovo">
         <div id="drakeBorder">
            <div id="drake">
               
               Be here when rappers <span style="color:#ffe700;">X</span> and <span style="color:#ffe700;">Y</span> will be performing live on stage.
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="upComing">
         Upcoming Events:

         <div id="entireBox">
            <div id="box">
               
               Make sure you are here when <br>these two teams clash in the<span style="opacity:0;">.............<!-- i used these full stops to push my text to the right --> ......</span> <span style="color:#ffe700; font-size:40px;">Manchester United vs Ajax</span><br>               biggest match in European <br> football the Europa league final.
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      
      <img src="http://xoio.de/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/GMP_Tokyo_Stadium_Concert_interiorvisual_by_xoio1.jpg" alt="concert stadium" style="width:100%; position:absolute; padding-top:70px; height:930px">
      <div id="navBar">
         <div id="circle1" class="circles">
         </div>
         <div id="circle2" class="circles">
         </div>
         <div id="circle3" class="circles">
         </div>
         <div id="circle4" class="circles">
         </div>
         <div id="Logo">
            <div class="holder">
               <div class="circle"></div>
               <div class="circle"></div>
               <div class="circle"></div>
               <div class="circle"></div>
               <div class="circle"></div>
               <div class="circle"></div>
               <div class="circle"></div>
               <div class="circle"></div>
               <div class="circle"></div>
               <div class="circle"></div>
               <div class="circle"></div>
               <div class="circle"></div>
               <div class="circle"></div>
               <div class="circle"></div>
               <div class="circle"></div>
               <div class="circle"></div>
            </div> <span id="google">Ice Arena</span>

         </div>

         <ul id="select">
            <li>
               <a class="highlight" style="color:#ffe700;">Home
              </a> </li>
            <li><a class="highlight" href="IceArenaGallery.html">
               Gallery
           </a> </li>
            <li> <a class="highlight" href="IceArenaOrderForm.html">
               Order Form 
           </a> </li>
            <li> <a class="highlight" href="#">
               The Arena
            </a></li>
            <li><a class="highlight" href="#">
               Contact Us
           </a> </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
 
      <ul id="eventList">
         <li class="event"><a class="eventLight" href="#">
            All<strong style="opacity:0;">.....................</strong>
           </a>
            <hr class="lines">
         </li>
         <li class="event"><a class="eventLight" href="#">
               Sports <strong style="opacity:0;">.............</strong>
               </a>
            <hr class="lines"> </li>
         <li class="event"><a class="eventLight" href="#">
               Music<strong style="opacity:0;">...............</strong>
            </a>
            <hr class="lines">
         </li>
         <li class="event"><a class="eventLight" href="#">
               Family<strong style="opacity:0;">..............</strong>
            </a>
            <hr class="lines">
         </li>
         <li class="event"><a class="eventLight" href="#">
               Comedy<strong style="opacity:0;">............</strong>
           </a>
            <hr class="lines"> </li>

         <li class="event"><a class="eventLight" href="#">
               Performance<strong style="opacity:0;">...</strong>
            </a></li>

      </ul>
      
      <div id="Events" style="opacity:0.4;">

      </div>


   </div>
   
   
</body>
<a href="#" class="rainbow-button" title="Home"></a>

</html>
```